# Vectorise nested for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I'm wondering if it is possible to vectorise the nested for loop in my code to speed up the code. I am basically trying to split (or trim) an image into smaller bits.

```py
import numpy as np 
import os 
from PIL import Image

image_path = 'sample.png'
number_of_rows = 4

input_np_arr_image = np.asarray(Image.open(image_path))
height, width = input_np_arr_image.shape[0:2]

height_trimmed = (height // number_of_rows) * number_of_rows
width_trimmed = (width // number_of_rows) * number_of_rows

trimmed_image = input_np_arr_image[:height_trimmed, :width_trimmed]

image_pieces = [np.hsplit(segment, 4)
                for segment in np.vsplit(trimmed_image, 4)
               ]
```

I then try to save the result using this nested for loop

```py
for row in range(len(image_pieces)):
    for col in range(len(image_pieces[row])):

        # create output image name
        segment_name = f"{image_path[:len(image_path)-4]}_{row}_{col}{image_path[-4:]}"
            
        # convert array to image 
        label_image = Image.fromarray(image_pieces[row][col])
            
        # make output directory for saving
        output_directory = "split_images"
        os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok = True)
        label_image.save(output_directory +"/"+ segment_name)
```

I'm curious if it's possible to do this without using the nested for loops. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you can vectorize. The list comprehension looks nice, but you don't really need the list of image pieces, if you have to loop through the image part with a for loop. It should be possible to do the image split in the for loop instead.

Comment: `numpy` "vectorization" basically means doing whole-array calculations, using the compiled numpy methods and functions.  That doesn't apply here.  You are writing a file, with a custom file name.  That `Image.fromarray` and`label_image.save` are PIL processes.  `numpy` can't "vectorize" that.

Comment: In fact, your code is certainly bound by IO-operations or eventually the compression of the image. If you use a SSD, then multithreading may help a bit. Storing many small files tends not to be fast. Storing a big one that contains many image (like games does with UV mapping) is much better but it is not always possible. I strongly advise you to *profile* your code before trying arbitrary optimizations based on guesses.